# Root without usb?

Tags: rooting, bluetooth, networking

I searched for something similar to this question already but I'm wondering if it's possible to root an android device without the usb connection. The port itself is damaged so I must use Bluetooth or network connection.

Device: Galaxy Centura SCH-S738C(GP)
Android 4.0.4

Comment: There are certain apps that allow rooting from the phone itself, but I can't cite a source here.

Comment: If anyone knows any apps or another solution that would be great if not I'll try and search for them online in the mean time thank you

Comment: Please add device and OS details by editing your question

Comment: Look up towel root. May or may not be compatible with your device/software version

Comment: Look for 'one-click root' apps on web.

Comment: Usually "one-click root" solutions still require a computer. It would be better to direct the OP to search for [SCH-S738C root without pc](https://www.google.com/search?q=SCH-S738C+root+without+pc&oq=SCH-S738C+root+without+pc&aqs=chrome..69i57.1230j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick Google search and found this: [How To Root Most Qualcomm phones without pc](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2204259) on XDA. The SAMSUNG GALAXY CENTURA - SCH-S738C is on the list of tested devices. Here are some details from the XDA post I am referencing:

> 1) [Download and Install poot.apk](http://www.mediafire.com/download/vyn7mv413nnm3cv/poot-debug.apk).
>
> 2) Now open the poot app then it will require you to install Ministro
>   II, Simply follow the link to Google play store.
>
> 3) Then you will be required to update ministro library, please update
>   it.
>
> 4) Once you updated the Ministro Library then you will be faced with
>   two options;
>   1. “Press here to Poot”.
>   2. “Built in root check”.
>
> 5) Click on the first option which is “Press here to Poot” and after a
>   while, You are going to face with three options:
>   1. Get Superuser.
>   2. Get root-checker.
>   3. In-built rootchecker.
>
> 6) Press Get superuser and download superuser app.
>
> 7) And finally do a reboot to take effect.
>
> Tested Devices:
> MICROMAX A54
> MICROMAX A56
> MICROMAX
>   A57
> MICROMAX A87
> KARBON A21
> Huawei U8860 Honor
> HUAWEI
>   ASCEND Y
> SAMSUNG GALAXY MINI 2 S6500
> SAMSUNG GALAXY CENTURA -
>   SCH-S738C
> SAMSUNG GALAXY DISCOVER - S730M
> Samsung Galaxy S Duos
>   S7562
> Samsung Galaxy ACE 2X
> LG Optimus Sol E730
> Alcatel
>   OT-908
> Gygabyte GSmart G1345
> Sony Ericsson WT19i Live with
>   Walkman
> Sony Xperia Tipo (Single/Dual)
> Sony Ericsson Xperia
>   Ray
> HTC Desire Z
> ZTE V790
> Ninetology Pearl Mini
>   i5350
> Kyocera Hydro C5170
> And still counting...

Please note that I did not write these steps nor have I tested this process. I take no responsibility for what this does to your device or for the grammar in the quote above. All credit goes to [dhinesh77 on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4981890).